# Нужна помощь в реализации интерфейса

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-xml

Хочу отрисовать на экране 4 элемента. Использую для этого LinearLayout, проблема в том, что мне нужно что бы 3 из них имели высоту wrap_content, а 1 match_parent. Все вроде как просто, но у меня почему-то творится какая-то вакханалия на экране, когда я пытаюсь затестить наработки. Ниже приведу код xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:clickable="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/details_view" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="225dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="food Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="225dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:text="Food description" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/description"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
            android:text="Price" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/additions"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/description"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="More " />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/addition_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Add to order" />

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: не помешает какая то схема, как все должно выглядеть на экране.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем `Relative Layout` позиционируйте элементы в `Preview` режиме, то есть переносите нужные `View` элементы на экран и расставляйте их как надо. Или попробуйте `Relative Layout` заменить на `Linear Layout` с нужной вам ориентацией `Vertical || Horizontal` и далее позиционируйте по весу:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

В первых трех `view` элементах, а четвертый `match_parent`. Или же